# How to print the name of the files that are processed?

Tags: spring-batch

I am using `MultiResourceItemReader` to read multiple csv files from a directory. I would want to log the file names when the read of records from it starts.  Tried the option of my Pojo implements `ResourceAware` & printing the `resource.getFileName()`. But this method gets invoked every time.

Is there a way to have the `fileName` only once when the read starts ?

Answer (score 1):

I would extends the `MultiResourceItemReader` and override `setResources()`:

```
@Override
void setResources(Resources resources) {
    // print out using `resources`
    super.setResources(resources);
}
```